# Can an SVN checkout be multi-threaded?

Tags: multithreading, svn, https, webdav

I have a repo with 30k+ small files, and I can only access the server over the internet via `https://`.  Checkout are very, very slow.  On the order of hours.  Internet connection speed is ~20Mbs and local machine is 3Ghz multi-core & 10k RPM HD.

(`svn://` protocol is not an option, sadly.)

So my question:

Can svn do a multi-threaded parallel checkout of a working copy?

It looks like the svn checkout is going file-by-file in a sequential order.  There is a minuscule delay between each file and I suppose that's the http request/reply and possibly my local filesystem's delays.  (Perhaps a little server filesystem latency as well?)

Thanks

Comment: I would imagine (although I haven't checked) that checkout time would be dominated by I/O bandwidth.  I would be interested to know if that's not the case.

Comment: Such an obvious hack like the one you're trying to attempt is clearly an indication that something is fundamentally wrong with the environment. Perhaps you'd be better off asking another question which describes your situation and ask for suggestions on how things might be better optimized. For example, why are there 30,000 files in a single SVN repo. Maybe it's time to split them up a bit?

Comment: @spencer The repo is large, but this is not up to me.  I know that other layouts are better, but since this is not in my control, I did not ask that question.

Comment: Oli: Yes, unsurprisingly bandwidth is a big factor.  I note a much larger lag when my internet connection is slower.

Comment: @Jeanne: So multi-threading the checkout won't speed things up much, then...

Comment: Though, per the OP,  multi-threading should help as raw internet speed is not an issue here.

Comment: @Oli It wouldn't help *me* because I'm downloading large files.  The actual problem in this thread sounds like the problem is there sheer # of files.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know of a command, but you could write a small Python (or the tool of your choice) script to help.  "svn list" gives you the name of each subdirectory.  You can then do a checkout of each subdirectory in the background so they happen in parallel.  You may need to do this at the 2nd/3rd/whatever level deep depending on your directory structure and where all the tiny files reside.

I'm assuming you don't have 30K files in the same directory of course.

Comment: That's not a bad idea.  You could probably use a series of shallow checkouts, too.   Does any tool already do this?

Comment: This answer sounds wrong for me. Maybe I am missing something. If you checkout each of the subdirectories individually then the root directory will not be a svn'ed folder. So later when you want to update or commit the entire directory tree you will have to do it for each of the subdirectories.

Comment: you can checkout root directory with `--depth immediates`. (This will checkout only immediate subfolders) Then update subfolders individually with `--set-depth infinity`

Answer (score 9):

You can use GNU Parallel for parallel svn checkouts.
Example-

```
svn ls 'https://foo/bar' | parallel svn export 'https://foo/bar/'{}
```

This will start parallel svn checkouts under 'bar' directory.

Answer (score 2):

Might sparse checkouts (newer SVN versions, >= 1.6 or so!) happen to help performance-wise?

```
time svn co --depth=empty http://URI

cd svn_repo_root/

time svn up --depth=infinity *
```

Also, perhaps it's useful to supply server and/or client with SSDs in order to work around bad operating system or SVN server/client implementation performance in the case of multi-lookup of many small files (due to seek time latency thoroughly dominating file system operations in case of small files - seeking is much less of a problem with SSDs).

And perhaps it's worth ensuring cache-hotness of all files on the server in advance of checking things out, by writing a script to parse through the entire repository tree on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't think of any reason why SVN could not checkout more than one file at a time,  I don't know any SVN client that does so.

Answer (score -1):

Would it not depend a lot on the ping time to the server?

If the ping is long, then you may not be able to do anything about it.

There is also a chance that the router that handles the firewall is falling behind and using something like stateful packet inspection, ie looking at each packet. the router can be changed to let stuff from the svn server escape packet scanning.

Comment: The ping-time or 'latency' in theory only affects the time it takes for the first packet to arrive. Because SVN does a lot of sequential back-and-forward request, the idea of using parallelism is very valid. If the bottleneck was pure bandwidth, parallelism would not help at all.